# Почему не работают асинхронные запросы aiohttp Python?

Tags: python, запрос, asyncio, aiohttp

Суть: у меня есть код с асинхронными запросами.

```
async def parsing(session, url):
    async with session.get(url=url) as response:
        response_text = await response.text()
        colors = ['Массив из других ссылкок']
        for color in colors:
            async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as sess:
                async with sess.get(url=color) as resp:
                    print(1)

async def load_card_data():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        links = ['Массив из ссылок']
        tasks = []
        for link in links:
            task = asyncio.create_task(parsing(session, link))
            tasks.append(task)
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


def main():
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(load_card_data())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

У меня вопрос: Почему, когда я пробегаюсь по colors через обычный requests, он выводит 1 нормально, а когда я захожу через asyncio, он не выводит 1 => не заходит после async with sess.get ?
Помогите, без вас не смогу разобраться

upd:

```
async def parsing(session, url):
    async with session.get(url=url) as response:
        response_text = await response.text()
        colors = ['Массив из других ссылкок']
        for color in colors:
            response = requests.get(url=color)
            print(1)
...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Добавьте код как вы делаете через requests

Comment: @insolor Добавил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

await будет ждать вашего результата внутри вашего цикла. Если вы хотите вызывать все одновременно, вам нужно вызывать все из внешнего цикла и собирать результаты.

Вот как это сделать

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp

async def call(session: aiohttp.ClientSession, url: str, image):
    image_bytes = pil_to_bytes(image)
    async with session.post(url, data=image_bytes) as response:
        return await response.text()


async def call_all(url:str, tasks: list):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        results = await asyncio.gather(
            *[call(session, url, img) for img, target in tasks], 
            return_exceptions=True
        )
        return results


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
res = loop.run_until_complete(
    call_all('http://localhost:8080/predictions/resnet50', dataset_val)
)
```